# Does getting a variable in a singleton map manager many times cost much more than getting it from the current object?

Tags: c#, algorithm, a-star

I am currently doing a Tower Defense (c#, unity) using a* algorithm, where the unit has to get neighbours in the MapManager by looking values in a Matrix[22,22] of int (that represents the map) in order to execute the a*.

0 is an obstacle, 1 is the beginning, 2 is the end, 3 is a free spot for towers.

I was wondering, if a call like that :

```
MapManager.Instance.Matrix[i,j];
```

costs a lot? Should I consider doing the a* where there is the matrix in the MapManager?

I don't copy the Matrix in each unit object where there is the a*.

Comment: No, it's fast. You shouldn't worry about microperformance like this though. Just code it, and if it's slow, run it through a profiler.

Comment: Thank you ! yes it's the same, I used a stopwatch and I did 40 000 iterrations on both. I get same result.